# How to configure dropwizard/CodaHale metrics in spring mvc without any third party Integration(eg ryantenny)

Tags: spring-mvc, codahale-metrics

I want to integrate codahale-metrics annotations in my project spring MVC project using annotation without any third party integration(like rynatenney @EnableMetrics).

Is there any alternate method to configure codahale-metrics without using (@EnableMetrics) so that I can use codahale-metrics annotations(@Timed,@Metered etc) in my project.